# Too Many Inactive Session in Oracle 19C

Tags: oracle, jdbc, c3p0, oracle19c, ojdbc

Our application usage c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar and ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar to connect with Oracle 19C.

Here are the flags being passed

`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@a07b9a4b [ connectionPoolDataSource ->com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@74b02295 [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, identityToken -> 31qzq3ay1xf5c0jx94505|6f4d2294, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 5, initialPoolSize -> 0, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 45, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 0, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@d898aa34 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 31qzq3ay1xf5c0jx94505|6d9428f3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:orcl, properties -> {user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 31qzq3ay1xf5c0jx94505|900649e, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]]`

Executed the following query:

select  status,  program, username, last_call_et
from v$session WHERE STATUS = 'INACTIVE';

| USERNAME | STATUS | PROGRAM | LAST_CALL_ET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMPDB | INACTIVE | JDBC Thin Client | 1727905 |
| EMPDB | INACTIVE | JDBC Thin Client | 1727904 |

I see that there are more than 250 inactive session created in Oracle 19c.

Does inactive session causes CPU Spike where Oracle DB Server is hosted?

How to find the root cause of why the inactive session is getting created?

Is there any way we can mitigate this from Application Server by setting up some properties?

I tried to investigate the root cuase but no luck .

I'm looking for the solution to find the exact root casue of these inactives session (from Oracle DB Server end and from Application End).

Comment: Is that 250 sessions for the `EMPDB` user, or 250 sessions for the entire database (all users)?

Comment: inactive sessions don't put any load on the database. they merely tie up a tiny, insignificant amount of PGA memory. But if it snowballs to a point that you reach the max sessions setting, you'll no longer be able to log in. It's important to close sessions no longer in use simply to prevent reaching the session limit. Until you solve that, it might behoove your DBA to write a job that kills these sessions when `LAST_CALL_ET` is obviously excessive as shown here.

Comment: Yes 250 session for EMPDB only.

Answer (score 0):

An `inactive` status only means that a session isn't doing anything at the *exact* moment you checked `v$session`. It is idle, awaiting its next SQL command. *Most* sessions are inactive at any given time, including background sessions generated by Oracle to perform internal database operations. This is in itself is not a resource issue or cause for concern: **this is normal, expected behavior** for most sessions.

A total of several hundred sessions to support background processes and user operations is not unusual, depending on your exact setup. For most configurations, each session maps to a dedicated process with reserved memory on the DB server, so if there's any cause for concern over resources it would be for memory usage.

If your application is generating more user sessions (for `empdb`?) than prescribed in the session pool parameters, you may have a session "leak" of some kind, which you would need to troubleshoot the root cause from the application side. Monitor the number of application sessions over time (not their status), and it it continues to grow unchecked this could be your issue. If the number remains constant over time then you're probably ok, assuming the application is working as expected.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations, on how can we identify the root cause from the Oracle Server Side?

Like what is the query application firing, so that the session goes inactive?

As it's a big application, I have searched all the possible connections we are closing but not sure if I'm missing something to  check.

If you can provide some query or way to identify the cause of inactive sessions on the Oracle server side will help me a lot.

Comment: Inactive sessions are *normal*; there is no "cause" to identify. Every session becomes inactive while it is waiting for its next instruction from the client. Because most commands are completed in a fraction of a second, this is *most* of the time. As long as the *number* of connections looks correct, there is nothing to troubleshoot. If there are too many connections, or too few, you'd have to troubleshoot the connection pool in the application; you can't fix that from inside the database.